# Public registration when system is off

Tags: registration

I have a site that I need to remain turned off for a while (while the client enters content). I do however need public user registration to be available.

Is it possible to make this one page visible even when the system is switched off in the settings?

Comment: Seems like you'd just want to leave the system on and deny access to all pages except for public registration though `.htaccess`?

Comment: Hey Brad. Yeah that's what I'm going to end up having to do. Didn't think there'd be a way but worth asking :)

Comment: Fair enough... be sure and add an official answer when you got a working `.htaccess` file. :)